# Please specify the product for which this rule should be applied

Tags: module, salesforce, odoo

Hi I want to ask about odoo sales module, when i want to create a pricelist they showed up like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0beN3.jpg)

Does anyone here know how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Please ask functional questions in the [official Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: This happens when the `Apply on` field (inside `Price rules`) is set to `Product Variant` and the `Variants` field is not set, The value of  `Apply on` is computed each time we update variants. You see that error because the ``Apply on`` is set to `Product variant`  after variants field value is set to False.  If you extended the `PricelistItem` model, make sure the `Apply on` field has the correct value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.